# Capture SignalR logging to file

Tags: logging, signalr

I'm using SignalR 1.2.

I have enabled client-side SignalR logging, plus `EnableDetailedErrors` is set to `true` when calling `MapHubs()` which results in very useful information being emitted to the Chrome dev tools console window for me.

Is there a means of capturing this information to disk somehow i.e. is there a SignalR config available to enable this? Reason I ask is that, when a disconnect event occurs, such as the user closing the browser, I'd like to capture that somehow. Saving the console output manually to Notepad (via copy and paste) is not ideal, since I would loose any disconnect event detail as the dev tool window will close once the browser is also closed.

Can this logging information be capture to disk for me?

Comment: Why don't you write to the debug console the output?

Comment: The logging from SignalR is being outputted to the console window. What I would like is for that content to be sent to a file instead.

Comment: I think I've got a hacky way of doing this. I can create my own `console` object and fake the `debug()` function. Thus I have `console.debug(message)` where I can save the `message` by any means I want.

Answer (score 2):

You can have SignalR write its server-side traces to files specified in Web.config:

```xml
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add name="traces" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="server_traces.txt" />
    </sharedListeners>
    <trace autoflush="true" />
    <switches>
      <add name="SignalRSwitch" value="All" />
    </switches>
    <sources>
      <source name="SignalR.Connection">
        <listeners>
          <add name="traces" />
        </listeners>        
      </source>
      <source name="SignalR.PersistentConnection">
        <listeners>
          <add name="traces" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="SignalR.ReflectedHubDescriptorProvider">
        <listeners>
          <add name="traces" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="SignalR.HubDispatcher">
        <listeners>
          <add name="traces" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="SignalR.MessageBus">
        <listeners>
          <add name="traces" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="SignalR.Transports.WebSocketTransport">
        <listeners>
          <add name="traces" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="SignalR.Transports.ServerSentEventsTransport">
        <listeners>
          <add name="traces" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="SignalR.Transports.ForeverFrameTransport">
        <listeners>
          <add name="traces" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="SignalR.Transports.LongPollingTransport">
        <listeners>
          <add name="traces" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat">
        <listeners>
          <add name="traces" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
  </system.diagnostics>
```

https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Tracing-on-the-server-side

---

If you are using a scaleout provider, you can also add sources for "SignalR.ScaleoutMessageBus", "SignalR.SqlMessageBus", "SignalR.ServiceBusMessageBus", and/or "SignalR.RedisMessageBus".

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/performance-and-scaling/scaleout-in-signalr

Comment: Excellent. I'll give that a go today.